# Make the last inline list item extend remaining width of container

Tags: css, list

I'm looking for a way to make the last inline list item extend the remainder of its container. So I have something like this.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li></li> //width = 50px
     <li></li> //width = 50px
     <li class="last"></li> //width needs to fill the remaining 300px
  </ul>
</nav>

nav {
  width:400px;
  height:50px;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Now the number of list items varies so I can't set the last list item to a set width. I need to make it fill whatever is left over in the width of the nav. How to with using css only?

Comment: Will the nav always be 400px wide? Or will it use percentages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display: table` (and `table-cell` and, at least for Firefox, `table-row`) with `table-layout: fixed` to get the table algorithm where indicated widths by the author (you) are applied by the browser and not the other way where the browser do its best to adapt the width of cells to their content.
Then applying a width of 50px to all "cells" except the last one.
I used `table-row` on `ul` and `table` on its `nav` parent because on Fx 18 setting `display: table` on `ul` didn't have the expected effect (something related to the browser having to create the missing parts a.k.a. a *shadow* element acting as row in-between). 
Being very descriptive (*this element must be rendered as a table and this one as a row and these ones as cells*) helps.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/X6UX9/1/

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li> //width = 50px</li>
     <li>//width = 50px</li>
     <li class="last">//width (...) 300px</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
}
nav > ul {
        display: table-row;
}
nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding:5px;
    outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
nav li:not(:last-child) {
    width: 50px;
}
```

PS: using `:last-child` for setting widths is compatible with IE9+, not IE8+ as I stated in the fiddle...

edit: oops I didn't see your `.last` class on last `li`. Well, you get the idea :)
edit2: updated fiddle using this class and neither `:not()` nor `:last-child` pseudo

Comment: Well luckily I can use a specific selector for items not first and last so I can do it that way. This is a nice method I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @Michael true, thanks. I updated the answer accordingly and it now uses `.last` and `width: auto` to "undo" the `width: 50px` on this last "cell".

Answer (score 2):

Update for 2019 :

```
ul { 
    display: flex;
}
ul li:last-child {
    flex: 1; 
}
```