# ul as tabs with single variable length li

Tags: html, css

I have created an `<ul>` that contains several fixed-width tabs (say 25px), but I need to make one of the `<li>` "tabs" consume the rest of the width of the `<ul>`.  This variable length `<li>` will contain another list of "tabs" that are dynamically loaded and can be cycled to see all available.  I've tried making the `<ul>` have a `position: absolute` and more, but can't seem to figure this out.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="scroll" style="float: right;" title="Scroll Right">&gt;&gt;
<li>ABC
<li>123
<li class="scroll" title="Scroll Left">&lt;&lt;
<li class="dynamictabs">  <!-- this needs to fill the rest of the width -->
   <ul>
    <li>first dynamic tab
    <li>second dynamic tab
    <li>...
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.tabs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  z-index: 20; }
.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.2; }

.tabs ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  right: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden; }
.tabs ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto; }
```

Comment: are you aware you have no closing `</li>` tags?

Comment: @imulsion They're optional unless it's XHTML.

Comment: @Juhana I know, just pointing it out :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip imulsion, but not XHTML as specified by Juhana :)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737863/make-the-last-inline-list-item-extend-remaining-width-of-container

Comment: @Thomas I'll take a look at the link real quick to see if I can make any headway! Thanks!

Comment: I've tried adding the 'table' css, but now everything is rendered VERY badly.  Float and position values don't appear to be acknowledged using the 'table' css.

Comment: you will need to clean up your CSS and HTML to use that method. no more float required.

Comment: @hmhcreative I can probably fix the float, but the absolute positioning will need to remain. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to work a little on the border, like wrap the text inside `li` in a `span`, then do border for that `span` instead of `li`.

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">

<li>ABC
<li>123
<li class="scroll" title="Scroll Left">&lt;&lt;
<li class="dynamictabs">  <!-- this needs to fill the rest of the width -->
   <ul>
    <li>first dynamic tab
    <li>second dynamic tab
    <li>...
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="scroll" title="Scroll Right">&gt;&gt;
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.tabs > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tabs .dynamictabs {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.tabs .dynamictabs ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help hmhcreative, but we're using pre-written code to interact with <ul> so my solution will need to retain that structure.

Comment: I've tweaked the code slightly (obviously), but this solution appears to be what worked!  Thanks hmhcreative!

Comment: I may have spoke to soon...  The tabs in the dynamic length <li> of the parent <ul> just wraps the child <li>'s.  I've tried applying 'overflow: hidden', but no go.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If I apply 'width: 200%' to the '.tabs .dynamictabs ul', the display is correct again, but then I'm mandating the width.  I need it dynamic.

Comment: can you wrap that `ul` inside a `div` like this? `<div style="height: 24px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 0px;">`